# Getting the error in Flutter 'Expected a value of type 'List<dynamic>', but got one of type '({bool growable}) => List<dynamic>''

Tags: flutter, dart

I am getting the below error in Flutter when trying to dynamically form a List and display the same in the UI.

'Expected a value of type 'List', but got one of type '({bool growable}) => List''

Below is how I form the List:

```
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    List items = jsonDecode(response.body)['result'].toList;
    List<Contract> tempContractResults = [];
    for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
      Contract temp = Contract.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body)['result'][i]);
      tempContractResults.add(temp);
    }

    List<Contract> contractResults = tempContractResults;
```

Object class:

```
class Contract {
  final String contractId;

  Contract(
      {this.contractId});

  factory Contract.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Contract(
        contractId: json['contractId'].toString(),
  }
}
```

And below code to display the list -

```
child: FutureBuilder<List<Contract>>(
    future: futureAlbum,
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasData) {
        if (snapshot.data != "") {
          return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return Text(snapshot.data[index].contractId);
            },
          );
```

Could anyone guide me on what could be the issue. I was thinking on the lines that the flutter considers static list and growable list differently and hence the issue. I tried some casting, but could not work it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you forgot to add the parenthesis to `.toList()` (you used `.toList`)?

```dart
List items = jsonDecode(response.body)['result'].toList();
```

Comment: Thanks much!!! it was the problem..